# Скролинг в flex контейнере

Tags: css, flexbox

Есть блок

```
<div style="display: flex;flex-direction:column;justify-content: flex-end;height: 400px;overflow: auto;">
Content
</div>
```

По идеи, при наполнеии этого блока, должен появляться скроллбар. Но контент просто ибрезаеться. Как это исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Флексы не нужны

```css
.flex-container {

  height: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
}
.message {
  padding:10px;
  margin:10px;
  border-radius:5px;
}
.message.to {
  border:1px solid #99f;
    display:inline-block;
}
.message.from {
  border:1px solid #aec;
  display:inline-block;
}
.from-left {
display:flex;
  justify-content:flex-start;
}
.from-right {
display:flex;
  justify-content:flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
<div class="from-left">
<div class="message from">Hello world</div>

</div>
<div class="from-right">
<div class="message to">Lorem Ipsum</div>

</div>
<div class="from-left">
<div class="message from">Hello world</div>

</div>
<div class="from-right">
<div class="message to">Lorem Ipsum</div>

</div>
<div class="from-left">
<div class="message from">Hello world</div>

</div>
<div class="from-right">
<div class="message to">Lorem Ipsum</div>

</div>
<div class="from-left">
<div class="message from">Hello world</div>

</div>
<div class="from-right">
<div class="message to">Lorem Ipsum</div>

</div>
<div class="from-left">
<div class="message from">Hello world</div>

</div>
<div class="from-right">
<div class="message to">Lorem Ipsum</div>

</div>

</div>
```

Comment: У меня вертикальный скролл. попробуйте Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>......

Comment: покажите на картинке желаемый результат, я не пойму что вы хотите в итоге.

Comment: Видели чат вк. Тот маленикий слева внизу. Что то типа того

Comment: обновил это то?